# will be assumed to return id

Tags: iphone

I import oourafft.h and oourafft.m class, but get strange error while ooura initialize.

```
OouraFFT * myFFT = [OouraFFT initForSignalsOfLength:1024 numberOfWindows:10];
```

OouraFFT may not respond to +initForSignalsOfLength: numberOfWindows

Messages without matching method signature will be assumed to return 'id' and accept argument   - Warning

I think that it some kind of error import .h file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to call class method which does not exist in OouraFFT - this method is instance method, so you need to allocate object at first.

You should do the following:

```
OouraFFT * myFFT = [[OouraFFT alloc] initForSignalsOfLength:1024 andNumWindows:10];
```

And don't forget that you own object after this, therefore you should release or autorelease in an appropriate place.

Comment: Double check with OouraFFT.h that you use the right method.

I found in Google CodeSearch OouraFFT and there is only method
- (id)initForSignalsOfLength:(int)numPoints andNumWindows:(int)numberOfWindows

which means that you misspelled the last parameter - should be andNumWindows instead of numberOfWindows

Comment: http://github.com/alexbw/iPhoneFFT have mis code  - Yes it work. 
OouraFFT * myFFT = [[OouraFFT alloc] initForSignalsOfLength:1024 andNumWindows:10];